# Using XDocument.XPathSelectElement with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, xml

I'm having an issue with selecting an element where the XPath has multiple conditions. Consider the following XML.

```
<Loan>
    <Assets>
        <Asset>
            <Field name="1003AssetBelongsTo" value="MAX JONES"/>
            <Field name="1003AssetCompanyDepository" value="PROCEEDS FROM SALE OF HOME"/>
            <Field name="1003AssetMarketVal" value="74000"/>
        </Asset>
        <Asset>
            <Field name="1003AssetBelongsTo" value="JOHN SMITH"/>
            <Field name="1003AssetCompanyDepository" value="CASH"/>
            <Field name="1003AssetMarketVal" value="2500"/>
        </Asset>
    </Assets>
</Loan>
```

The following line gives me the second Asset where the `value` attribute of the `Field` element is "JOHN SMITH". This is fine.

```
var element = loanXDoc.XPathSelectElement("//Loan/Assets/Asset[Field/@value='JOHN SMITH']");
```

Now I want to have multiple conditions. So, for example:

```
var element = loanXDoc.XPathSelectElement("//Loan/Assets/Asset[Field/@name='1003AssetCompanyDepository' and Field/@value='JOHN SMITH']");
```

For the second sample there are no Asset elements where the `Field/@name` attribute is `1003AssetCompanyDepository` AND the `Field/@value` attribute is `JOHN SMITH`. My expected result is the second line of code would return no elements found. My actual result is the second Asset for `JOHN SMITH` is still returned. It's like the `and` is behaving like an `or`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not selecting the same `Field` element with your predicate, but rather two different elements.
With

```
//Loan/Assets/Asset[Field/@name='1003AssetCompanyDepository' and Field/@value='JOHN SMITH']
```

you're selecting an `<Asset>` element which has both - a `<Field>` element with an `@name` attribute with the value `1003AssetCompanyDepository` and another `<Field>` element with a `@value` attribute with the value `JOHN SMITH`.
So the output is correct.

To get the right output, use the following expression:

```
//Loan/Assets/Asset[Field[@name='1003AssetCompanyDepository' and @value='JOHN SMITH']]
```

It selects all the `<Asset>` elements which have both properties in *the same* `<Field>` element. Here, in this case, the result is empty.